# Binary Search Algorithmn - infinity loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, binary-search

I have a problem with my Binary Search algorithm. I'm trying to implement it in javascript but still it get a infinity loop. Here's my code:

```
var a = [1, 4, 5, 8, 11, 15]

function binarySearch(arr, item){
  let low = 0
  let high = arr.length - 1

  while(low <= high) {
    var m = (low + high)/2 | 0
    if(arr[m] == item){
        console.log("Item found in index: " + m)
      return false;
    } else {
            if(a[m] > item){
            console.log("Too high")
          h = m - 1
        } else {
            console.log("Too low")
          l = m + 1
        }
    }
  }
  console.log("Item not found")
  return false;
}

binarySearch(a, 1)
```

Comment: You should `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil` the value `(low + high) / 2` before assigning it to `m`. And you should use the same variables either `low` and `high` or `l` and `h`, not both.

Comment: `while(low <= high)` You don't actually modify either of those variables inside the loop so if the condition starts as true it can never become false.

Comment: Ok, thanks i didn't noticed that i use "l" and "h" instead of "low" and "high". Now it's working, thanks a lot. Btw. Math.floor is working the same as | 0

Comment: @sh3ev, no, bitwise OR converts a number to first to 32 bit and then back to 64 bit float, whereas `Math.floor` keeps the number in 64bit float.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this (editted something wrong from your code):**

```
var a = [1, 4, 5, 8, 11, 15]

function binarySearch(arr, item) {
    var low = 0
    var high = arr.length - 1

    while (low <= high) {
        let m = low + (high - low ) / 2
        if (arr[m] == item) {
            console.log("Item found in index: " + m)
            return false;
        }
        if(a[m] > item) {
            console.log("Too high")
            hight = m - 1
        } else {
            console.log("Too low")
            low = m + 1
        }
    }
    console.log("Item not found")
    return false;
}
```

binarySearch(a, 1)